# use d3 v3 instead of d3 v4 react js

Tags: reactjs, react-d3

I am importing d3 library using:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
```

But it gives me this error:

```
15:20-27 "export 'time' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'
```

The reason being, the code is using d3 v3 and I am importing d3 v4. How do I restrict it to using d3 v3 instead ? In package.json, then d3 version looks like:

```
"d3": "^5.1.0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the latest v3 version setting it directly in your package.json:

```
"d3": "3.5.17"
```

Then proceed to install again the packages with your favorite package manager:

```
npm install
```

or

```
yarn install
```

If using npm and having a version upper than 5, I would suggest you to delete first the `package-lock.json` to avoid any problem.